# Can't set custom class for cell in table view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, storyboard, interface-builder

I'm really going crazy: **I can't simply set my custom class for a UITableViewCell** and I really don't know why.

### My project

[image]

In my **Storyboard** I have a **table view controller** set to use **ManageListsTVC.swift**.

I want use a **custom cell** with dynamic prototypes so I create a custom class **ListTVCell**:

```
import UIKit

class ListTVCell: UITableViewCell
{

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

So, clean, build, go in IB, select my table view controller, select the cell and...

[image]

I can't see my custom class! Why? Really, I waste so much time already for this stupid problem and I don't know what's wrong.

### What I already tried

- empty cache in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- restart Xcode
- clean project
- check if ListTVCell.swift appears in compiled sources

---

I'm using Xcode 6.3.1.

Comment: You mean you don't see the `ListTVCell` in dropdown? It may be bug in Xcode, try just to type it there

Comment: Have you tried adding a new swift file > pasting in your ListTVCell code > save > and seeing if it appears in the drop down? Just to rule out any config settings

Comment: Guys I don't know why but after a reboot of my Mac now I can see my custom class. Really strange but now everything works, I'll update my first post hoping to help someone else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

--> incredibly after a **complete reboot of my Mac** now everything works and I can set my custom class.

Really strange but I decide to reply to my post, maybe can be helpful for someone else.

Comment: No need to restart PC just force quite Xcode and start again.
This works in my case

Comment: Omg Thank you. I wasted 2 hours on this problem. Quitting Xcode normally fixed it for me